# How do I set focus to a text box Html.TextBoxFor - mvc 2

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, focus, html-helper

I'm trying to set focus on a text box which is generated in the following way:

```
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { style = "width:190px;Border:0px", maxsize = 190 })%>
```

I tried to use javascript which didn't help much :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       var txtBox = document.getElementById("Email");
       if (txtBox != null) txtBox.focus();
    </script>
```

How do I set focus to a text box Html.TextBoxFor in mvc 2 ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Where are you writing this javascript? You need to make sure that the DOM is loaded:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var txtBox = document.getElementById("Email"); 
    if (txtBox != null) { 
        txtBox.focus();
    }
};
```

Also HTML helpers might generate a different ID depending on the context: for example if you are calling the `TextBoxFor` inside an editor template.

Having said this it is not the solution I would recommend you. To solve all those problems I usually apply a css class to the textbox:

```
<%=Html.TextBoxFor(
    model => model.Email, 
    new { @class = "email", maxsize = "190" }) %>
```

where `email` class is defined like this:

```
.email {
    width: 190px;
    border: 0;
}
```

and then use a [popular javascript framework](http://jquery.com/) to set the focus when the DOM is ready:

```
$(function() {
    $('input.email').focus();
});
```

Comment: So bottom line, where do I put that script that sets the focus

Comment: You could put it in a javascript file which is where scripts usually go. If this script is included at the end of the DOM, you no longer need to wrap the focus call in a `document.ready` handler.

Answer (score 8):

you can use autofocus in [HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp) .
`<%=Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { style = "width:190px;Border:0px", maxsize = 190 ,autofocus = "autofocus" })%>`